# Python run both as user and sudo

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, bash

I'm writing a python script to automatize the installation of some tools every time I create a VM and, since I'm not a bash fan I'm doing it with python.
The problem is that `apt` installations require sudo privileges, while `pip` installations don't.

I'm looking for a way to downgrade my privileges back to normal user's after all apt installations.

At the moment I tryed a pretty ugly oneliner like `os.system(f"su {user} && ...")` or `subprocess.Popen(...)`

Is there a decent way?

Comment: Why not just run it as a normal user, and user `sudo` for running the `apt` commands?

Comment: ...or just use something like [ansible](https://ansible.com) instead, which has a declarative mechanism for specifying which tasks need to run with elevated privileges.

Comment: 1) I thought of it, but i was curious, since I didn't find anything useful on this, so I asked anyway 2) I didn't know ansible...

Comment: Note that methods of the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module are generally more flexible than using `os.system`, and you can also use `sudo` to drop privileges in a way that is often easier to work with than using `su`: `subprocess.check_call(['sudo', '-u' user, 'command', 'arg1', 'arg2', ...]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list of `apt` commands with `subprocess` or `pexpect`. It can also prompt for a password if no password is provided using `getpass`:

> **NOTE** - Tested on Ubuntu 20.04 using Python 3.8.10

> **NOTE** - Updated to use and test pipes.quote - Thx, pts!

```
import pipes
import shlex
import subprocess
from getpass import getpass

import pexpect

sudo_password = '********'
# First command in double quotes to test pipes.quote - Thx, pts!
commands = ["apt show python3 | grep 'Version'",
            'sudo -S apt show python3 | grep Version', ]

print('Using subprocess...')
for c in commands:
    c = str.format('bash -c {0}'.format(pipes.quote(c)))
    # Use sudo_password if not None or empty; else, prompt for a password
    sudo_password = (
            sudo_password + '\r'
    ) if sudo_password and sudo_password.strip() else getpass() + '\r'
    p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(c), stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    output, error = p.communicate(sudo_password)
    rc = p.returncode
    if rc != 0:
        raise RuntimeError('Unable to execute command {0}: {1}'.format(
            c, error.strip()))
    else:
        print(output.strip())

print('\nUsing pexpect...')
for c in commands:
    c = str.format('bash -c {0}'.format(pipes.quote(c)))
    command_output, exitstatus = pexpect.run(
        c,
        # Use sudo_password if not None or empty; else, prompt for a password
        events={
            '(?i)password': (
                    sudo_password + '\r'
            ) if sudo_password and sudo_password.strip() else (
                    getpass() + '\r')
        },
        withexitstatus=True)
    if exitstatus != 0:
        raise RuntimeError('Unable to execute command {0}: {1}'.format(
            c, command_output))
    # For Python 2.x, use string_escape.
    # For Python 3.x, use unicode_escape.
    # Do not use utf-8; Some characters, such as backticks, may cause exceptions
    print(command_output.decode('unicode_escape').strip())
```

**Output:**

```
Using subprocess...
Version: 3.8.2-0ubuntu2
Version: 3.8.2-0ubuntu2

Using pexpect (and getpass)...

Version: 3.8.2-0ubuntu2
[sudo] password for stack: 

Version: 3.8.2-0ubuntu2

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: This code (bash -c) works incorrectly if c contains a `'`. Use `pipes.quote(c)` and drop the `'`s to fix it.